# Convert JSON to POJO using Gson: JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, json, gson

i get a JSON response from a server and i want to transform it into a POJO which is the following:

```
public class MeasureDataGetPOJO {
    @SerializedName("CODE")
    private String code = null;

    @SerializedName("USER")
    private User user = null;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public class User {
        private List<MeasureData> measureDatas = null;

        public List<MeasureData> getMeasureDatas() {
            return measureDatas;
        }

        public void setMeasureDatas(List<MeasureData> measureDatas) {
            this.measureDatas = measureDatas;
        }

        public class MeasureData {

            @SerializedName("MT_TIME")
            private String time = null;

            @SerializedName("MT_VALUE")
            private String value = null;

            public String getTime() {
                return time;
            }

            public void setTime(String time) {
                this.time = time;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON i get from the server:

```
{
"CODE":"012",
"USER":
    [
        {
            "MT_TIME":"1412882760",
            "MT_VALUE":"319",
        }
    ]
}
```

And the error i get from Gson is:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 10
```

Is there something wrong with the JSON or with the POJO i try to map the JSON into?
I am expecting one user with multiple pairs of MT_TIME and MT_VALUE.

So i get a status code and a user object. the user has a array of pairs of MT_TIME and MT_VALUE.
Later there maybe will be more user informations in the user object.

It is just a guess but would this be the correct json?

```
{
"CODE":"012",
"USER": 
{
    "MEASURE_DATA": 
    [
        {
            "MT_TIME":"1412882760",
            "MT_VALUE":"319"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

with an additional SerializedName here:

```
@SerializedName("MEASURE_DATA")
private List<MeasureData> measureDatas = null;
```

Comment: No, the second JSON is totally invalid.  (Run it through an [online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to find out why.)  (And go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax.)

Comment: ("USER" is an array, and as such is normally represented by a List.  Only a JSON object maps to a POJO without gymnastics.)

Comment: thank you for the hint @HotLicks i corrected it. the json is not my business. my partner has to correct it because the pojo has to be like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected. From what your class says, the JSON should look like:

```
{
    "CODE": "012",
    "USER": {
        "MT_TIME": "1412882760",
        "MT_VALUE": "319",
    }
}
```

But the user field in the JSON you showed is inside an array.

If this means that what you expect is a list of users instead of just one user, then replace your field in the POJO with a `List<User>`; otherwise, fix the JSON.

Comment: no i dont expect multiple users. but i expect multiple value pairs of MT_TIME and MT_VALUE.

Comment: for the way you explained it is not possible to return more than one MT_TIME, MT_VALUE pair at once from the server.

Comment: Then from your code what you expect is a `List<MeasureData>`, right? Why call it `User` then?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. the measuredatas belonging to the user. there maybe will be some more user information later in the json and there is a List<MeasureData> inside my user

Comment: OK, are you responsible for producing the JSON? If you are, I believe you should start by defining your JSON inputs first. Otherwise you are in for quite a fight!

Comment: no im not responsible for the json. unfortunately. but i guess i got it. 
{
 "CODE":"012",
 "USER": 
 {
  MEASURE_DATA 
  [
   {
    "MT_TIME":"1412882760",
    "MT_VALUE":"319",
   }
  ]
 }
}

Comment: Sorry but you lost me here; you say you are not responsible for the JSON and yet you paste in a comment what the JSON should be like (notwithstanding the missing semicolon). So, what is what?

Comment: yeah it is like i said but i can provide the information to the guy whos responsible for the json. The json isnt fix. My partner can still change it. Missing semicolon?

Comment: Well then have your partner change it to suit your needs; this is the real answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need list of Users. See that after `"USER":` there is a `[` in your json String.

This is what the error is saying:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

Comment: No i only expect one user. but i expect multiple pairs of MT_TIME and MT_VALUE.

Comment: @Mulgard - According to the first JSON, a "USER" consists of an array of two objects.  Since there is nothing else to a "USER", it makes no sense to have an object for it.

Comment: it makes sence because of the rules of software engineering. there will be more user information in the future. i guess i found a solution and i posted it in my original post.